# Disable Apache logging completely

Tags: apache-http-server, logging

I have an old server running online with over 250 sites on it I am not sure, but maybe [too many logfiles in the apachelog are slowing down the server?](https://superuser.com/questions/589634/are-too-many-logfiles-in-the-apachelog-slowing-down-the-server)

Now since I don't need the Apache logs, How do I disable all logging completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disabled all vhosts logging with:

```
find /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/* -exec sed -i 's/#*[Cc]ustom[Ll]og/#CustomLog/g' {} \;
find /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/* -exec sed -i 's/#*[Ee]rror[Ll]og/#ErrorLog/g' {} \;
```

and commented out in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
#ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

and added

```
ErrorLog /dev/null
```

Restart apache gracefully:

```
apache2ctl graceful
```

I have a lot of logs in different places so I can watch the result with

```
 tail -n 1 -f /var/kunden/logs/*log /var/kunden/logs/*log /var/log/apache2/*log
```

If you want to enable all logging into one file you can edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` again and add those lines:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log  "%h %v %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
```

and comment out

```
#ErrorLog /dev/null
```

Answer (score 5):

For all who have the  `other_vhosts_access.log` file and want to disable it too, comment out the line:

```
#CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined
```

in:

```
/etc/apache2/conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf
```

or disable this config file:

```
sudo a2disconf other-vhosts-access-log
```

Comment: NO, `# Define an access log for VirtualHosts that don't define their own logfile`